# Can’t deploy app on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS after upgrade to Meteor 1.3

Tags: node.js, meteor, web-deployment

Everything worked fine until Meteor 1.3 upgrade. Now I've even tried to reconfigure new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS droplet from skratch, no success. Here is what I'm doing:

Installed NodeJS 0.10.x and Mongo.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | sudo bash -
apt-get install nodejs
apt-get install mongodb-server
```

Built app.

```
meteor build --architecture os.linux.x86_64
```

Uploaded it to server and extracted to `/home/production` and tried to install dependencies.

```
cd /home/production/bundle/programs/server && npm install
```

And here we are:

```
> fibers@1.0.8 install 
/home/production/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:108:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/production/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.43
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:108:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/production/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.43
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.8 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/production/bundle/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.43
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.29
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I even tried to use exact "meteor" versions of NodeJS and NPM: 0.10.43 and 2.14.22. No success. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I have no idea how could it work before 1.3 update without `make`. Maybe something really changed in Meteor itself in 1.3.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think previously `meteor build` specified a platform-specific precompiled `fibers` tarball in package.json, so there was no need to recompile it. Why that has changed, I don't know.